# What should I do if OP keeps rejecting my edits?

Tags: discussion, editing-help

I'm having a frustrating time making edits recently.

- I've improved the question, its formatting and added appropriate tags but the OP keeps rejecting it. See suggested edits [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6266488) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6266622).
- I've changed the answer from link-only by quoting the actual code from the link (suggested edit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6268227)) and the OP rejected it with **This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive**.

So my question is, should I give up and leave poorly formatted questions/answers which is written in broken English? How should one respond or act in such a situation?

I am not asking about why edits on the question (point 1) were rejected, as I feel people are assuming that. I am more concerned with the attitude of the user because link-only answers (point 2) are discouraged at SO and you have to be super-naive to not know that, especially when you consider that the user has 1K rep.

Comment: All the edits you've shown change their respective posts a lot. Though I wouldn't be so harsh as to undo the one you did with the answer, I undo the ones you did on the question right away. It almost seems like you are suggesting the OP didn't read the error messages and that would be the reason of their problem.

Comment: On your last edit: leave a comment that links may go stale and advise the OP to copy the relevant snippet (with attribution). In general: please, please, *please* try to avoid using `code` ticks `for` everything that looks like `code`; 'button', for example, in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910638/how-do-i-access-to-listview-from-the-adapter

Comment: Avoid pestering another SO user with repeated edits he doesn't like.  Once is enough.  If he doesn't like your intent then just move on, there's plenty more to edit.

Comment: @Renan hmm, well the question was not formatted as we normally do at SO. It wasn't as clear (broken English) and we're told to make our questions on SO.

Comment: @Jongware thanks for pointing that out. I'll take care of this. Btw I don't think having mentioned that ("links may go stale") would've changed the result.

Comment: @HansPassant agreed I shouldn't have. But what about the link-only edit? I guess only users with 2K+ rep could make edits for this guy. But I guess as you said, I should move on. :)

Comment: +1 on @Jongware's comment. I carefully use backticks as well as capitalization to distinguish between the same sequence of letters as an English word or as a quote from a program. A button in a display vs. a Java `Button` object. The general concept of an object vs. the `Object` referenced by a variable. Editors sometimes undo that by changing every use of the letter sequence to look like a code quote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short:

The author of the post is the ultimate judge for how their question should be presented to the world (short of vandalism). If they prefer a format that is difficult to read, there's not much you can really do about it from an editing standpoint. You'll need to let the moderation system (downvotes, closures, account suspension, etc.) do its job.

#### If the post is mediocre and you are trying to make it a bit better...

Then just walk away. Yeah, it'd be better if it was better, but acceptable is still acceptable. No point in getting into a little war over relatively trivial edits.

#### If the post is unreadable or violates some of SO's "rules"...

If you have less than 2,000 rep, your edits have to go through the review queue and the author can reject them. Once you get over that threshold, your edits are applied immediately. If the author rejects your attempts to salvage their question, then let someone with more rep make the edits. If the author rolls back those edits, then, if the question has little value or is off-topic without those edits, it will eventually be downvoted and closed.

#### If the author is vandalizing their own post...

This is very rare but does happen occasionally. If you see someone who knowingly and flagrantly edits their own posts so as to destroy content, flag it for moderator attention. Users are not allowed to vandalize any posts, including their own.